# find largest power of two less than X number?

Tags: find, python

I m doing this

```
def power_two(n, base = -1):
    result = 2 ** base
    if result < n:
        base += 1
        power_two(n, base)
    else:
        if result == n:
            print base
        else:
            print base - 1
```

what is the pythonic way to find largest power of two less than X number?

EDIT
example: power_two(100) return only the power

Comment: When you say less than, do you mean "less than or equal" or "strictly less than"? In other words, what should it return if n is an exact power of 2, for example 32?

Comment: What's "pythonic" about using logarithms?  Those are Python's antecedents by 377 years or so.

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: What I just said: logarithms.  Your answer is perfect.  It's just ... you know ... not really pythonic.  More "universally mathematical".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Find the logarithm and truncate it:

```
def power_two(n):
    return int(math.log(n, 2))
```

Comment: @mark: I mean return only 6, the "2**6" was to explain where the 6 come from, but you give me a pythonic way, thank you

Comment: In Python3.2: `int(math.log(4,2)) == 1`, but `int(math.log(8,2)) == 3`. It is an inconsistent behavior for `power_two()` function.

Comment: @Sebastian Probably it is a bug in Python 3.2. That would break compatibility with previous versions. Namely, Python 3.1.2 works as expected `math.log(4,2) = 2.0`.

Comment: @DimitrisLeventeas: [it is fixed but there is a debate whether or not it is a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue9959)

Comment: `power_two(2**2955)` gives an incorrect answer of 2954

Answer (score 22):

You could use [bit_length()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types):

```
def power_two(n):
    return n.bit_length() - 1
```

By definition for `n != 0`: `2**(n.bit_length()-1) <= abs(n) < 2**n.bit_length()`

Comment: This is a nice solution, although actually Tony Veijalainen actually already posted it - it's just his answer is less clear. I gave my +1 to him for being first to suggest it and also for mentioning that it requires Python 2.7 or newer which is a very real concern - many users are still on Python 2.6.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I've up-voted Tony Veijalainen as well (it was -1). Python 2.7 is the current version of CPython therefore I don't mention it explicitly (I use 2.4 at work so I understand where you're coming from). When I saw your answer I've thought that there must be some bit twiddling solution (MSB). `long.bits_in_digit()` is not public so `bit_length()` is the next best thing.

Answer (score 6):

Two ways, first works only in Python 2.7 and maybe 3+:

```
import random
for number in (random.randint(0,1<<32) for _ in range(16)):
    print "%20i,%4i, %4i" % (number, number.bit_length()-1, len(bin(number))-3)
```

Comment: The -3 part would be messed up  if binary would be negative.

Answer (score 1):

## utilising the power of .format!

```
def maxPowOf2(n):
     return len("{0:b}".format(n))-1
```

This answer is similar and maybe slower than @jfs though... 
translates the number into a binary string and finds the length.
Won't work properly on negative numbers though...

Answer (score -3):

Um well I'm sure the other suggestions work, but I feel they will perform awfully slow. I haven't actually verified any speeds, but this should be extremely fast!

This is also in Java. So you would need to convert it.

```
public static int getPowerOfTwo(int size)
{
    int n = -1;
    while (size >> ++n > 0);
    return (1 << n - 1 == size) ? size : 1 << n;
}

public static int getNextPowerOfTwo(int size)
{
    int n = -1;
    while (size >> ++n > 0);
    return 1 << n;
}

public static int getPreviousPowerOfTwo(int size)
{
    int n = -1;
    while (size >> ++n > 0);
    return 1 << n - 1;
}
```