# How to find and truncate a list to the nearest power of 2 (in the most pythonic way)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I have a list called `data`, and I want to truncate it so that it's length is a power of 2. The current method I use is the following:

```
n = 1                          # dummy variable
while len(data)/(2**n) > 1:
    n += 1

nearest_n = n - 1
data_trunc = data[0:2**nearest_n]
```

This does the job; however, it uses a dummy integer `n` for the `while` loop, which isn't very "pythonic".

Can someone provide a more **pythonic**, or **efficient** method?

**Reasoning:**

The reason I'm truncating `data` is because I want to perform an FFT. You can decrease the FFT compute time by using this trick, with little effect on the results.

An FFT works by breaking the data up into odd and even sets and the more times it can do this, the faster it computes. Hence, the more divisible the length is by 2, the more splits can be made, and the shorter the compute time is. In contrast, lists lengths that are prime numbers are the slowest.

I don't intend to spark a discussion on 'zero padding' vs. 'truncating' data for an FFT, but rather focus on the most pythonic way to find the nearest power of 2 for a given number.

Comment: Have a look at this previously asked [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797575/find-largest-power-of-two-less-than-x-number).

Comment: yeah that's it. good find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int (math.log (len (data), 2))
```